# Phonegap cordova 404 not found on Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, http-status-code-404

I'm making an application that need to use a distant http server. In the browser i have no trouble with ajax/inAppBrowser/iframe but when build and running in Android it doesn't work anymore.

I used the distant chrome debugger and just noticed all request returning  404 not found from cache, so i'm guessing the application does not have the right to make request on the web. I searched a solution but i can't figure out where it come from.

Here is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="foo" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"    xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>foo</name>
<description>
    foo
</description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">

</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist"/>
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
<engine name="android"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser"/>
```

I tried to start again from the beggining but this the simpliest. Some of the lines are maybe useless but i tried differents solutions to fix my problem.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at


http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0


Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->
<html>
<head>
    <!--
    Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
        https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
    Some notes:
        * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
        * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
        * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
            * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
    -->
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src   'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *"> -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' * ws://localhost:35729 data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *;script-src 'self' localhost:35729 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
  <center><div class="">
      <div id="deviceready" class="row col s12">
        <h1>foo</h1>
        <div class="input-field col s8">
          <input type="text" id="addr" name="addr" placeholder="Adresse">
        </div>
        <div class="input-field  col s4">
          <input type="text" id="port" placeholder="port">
        </div>
        <div class="input-field  col s12">
          <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Nom d'utilisateur">
        </div>
        <div class="input-field  col s12">
          <input type="password" id="pswd" placeholder="Mot de passe">
        </div>
        <button id="button_test" class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue lighten-1" value="tester">tester</button>
        <button id="button_start" class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue lighten-1" value="commencer">commencer</button>
      </div>
      <div id="result"></div>
      <div id="window-iframe"></div>
  </div></center>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

index.js

```
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */




var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');


        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');


        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};


function debug(string){
  $("#result").html($("#result").html()+"</br>"+string);
}


debug("ready");


document.getElementById("button_test").addEventListener("click", test);
document.getElementById("button_start").addEventListener("click", start);


document.getElementById("addr").value = localStorage.getItem("address");
document.getElementById("port").value = localStorage.getItem("port");
document.getElementById("name").value = localStorage.getItem("username");
document.getElementById("pswd").value = localStorage.getItem("password");


function test(){
  debug("connecting...");
  console.log("connecting...");
  addr = document.getElementById("addr").value;
  port = document.getElementById("port").value;
  username = document.getElementById("name").value;
  password = document.getElementById("pswd").value;


  url_req = "http://www.lemonde.fr/";
  // url_req = 'http://'+addr+':'+port;//'/actions.php?do=auth&login='+username+'&password='+password;
  debug("connecting...to->"+url_req)
  $.ajax({
      url: url_req,
      timeout: 30000,
      success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        debug("ajax sucess");
        console.log(data);
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        if(data.return == "success"){
          $("#result").html("OK");
        } else {
          debug("page return fail");
          $("#result").html(data.error);
        }
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        debug("error->"+thrownError);
      }
  });
  localStorage.setItem("address", addr);
  localStorage.setItem("port", port);
  localStorage.setItem("username", username);
  localStorage.setItem("password", password);
}


function start(){
  addr = document.getElementById("addr").value;
  port = document.getElementById("port").value;
  username = document.getElementById("name").value;
  password = document.getElementById("pswd").value;
  $("#window-iframe").html("<iframe src='http://www.lemonde.fr/' width='800px' height='600px'></iframe>");
  //var ref = window.open('http://www.lemonde.fr/', '_blank', 'location=yes');
}


app.initialize();
```

AndroidManifest

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="foo" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: @meitect whitelist plugin added?

Comment: Yes, removed en added again.

Comment: You may have to post the project in github for us to nail the issue